# Swift Realm - Query Empty Set but Data is in RealmBrowser

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, database, realm

I am new to iOS developing. I try to receive the data which is stored in realm Database but sometimes I get an empty set although I can see the data in RealmBrowser. Often it works, but it is not reliable.

At first I clear the stored data to get sure I am not going to display old data.
After that I insert it to the RealmDatabase and in addition to that I query all stored data to display it in the tableView.

Here is my code (Swift 3):

```
    let realm = try! Realm()
        try! realm.write {
            // clear all old data stored as fahrt.self
            //realm.delete(realm.objects(fahrt.self));
            realm.delete(realm.objects(fahrt.self));
            let nsArray = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data as Data, options: []) as! NSArray;
            for eintrag in nsArray{
                realm.create(fahrt.self, value: eintrag, update: false)
            }
            try! realm.commitWrite();

        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let temp = ui as! DisplayViewController;
            let realm = try! Realm()
            let result = realm.objects(fahrt.self)
            ui.showData(res: result);
            // sometimes result is empty , don't know why
        }
```

RealmModel:

```
class fahrt: Object {
dynamic var id:  Int = 0
dynamic var date = ""
dynamic var from_lang: Double = 0.0
dynamic var from_lon: Double = 0.0
dynamic var to_lang: Double = 0.0
dynamic var to_lon: Double = 0.0

override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
   return "id"
}
```

}

Comment: have you try print the `result` variable before show to ui?

Comment: also please add your code for the `fahrt` class

Comment: Yes, I inspected it in debug section, result is nil.
Probably a problem by clearing the objects in realmDatabase just before writing the new ones?

Comment: yes, probably, try add another `write` block for deleting

Comment: does not work either :/

Comment: just check on docs https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#threading. You cannot have multiple operation for a thread. maybe need to create seperate `let realm = try! Realm()` for delete and create

Comment: I already did it in a separate function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to include `realm.commitWrite()` inside a `realm.write { }` block. `realm.commitWrite()` is used in conjunction with `realm.beginWrite()`, but both of these are automatically called inside `realm.write { }`. :)

Secondly, when you perform a write transaction on a background thread, the changes are automatically exposed on the main thread on the next iteration of the run loop. However, in some cases, when immediately calling code on the main thread after a background write, it's possible this hasn't happened yet. To ensure Realm has the very latest copy of its data on the main thread, you should call `realm.refresh()` in that dispatch block before you perform the query.